# Facebook API Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I added Facebook SDK to my android app. I used callBackManager to handle the login button. Now I'm logged to Facebook and I want to save my fb profile information (profile photo, cellphone, name, birthdate..) before calling the function goRegisterActivity(). Any help?

```
 // Handle Facebook Login Button
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        facebookLoginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_facebook_btn);
        facebookLoginBtn.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                //Go to register first step activity
                goRegisterActivity();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                //Do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Oups! can't login Facebook. Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }});
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the graph API in the `onSuccess()` method:

```
 facebookLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.i("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                    // Get facebook data from login
                    Bundle bFacebookData = getFacebookData(object);

                    emailStr = bFacebookData.get("email").toString();
                    fnameStr = bFacebookData.get("first_name").toString();
                    lnameStr = bFacebookData.get("last_name").toString();
                    facebookIdStr = bFacebookData.get("idFacebook").toString();
                    genderStr = bFacebookData.get("gender").toString();
                    dp_url = bFacebookData.get("profile_pic").toString();


                }
            });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, email,gender, birthday, location"); // Parámetros que pedimos a facebook
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
       }
```

And The `getFacebookData(object)` method should be like:

```
private Bundle getFacebookData(JSONObject object) {

    try {
        bundle = new Bundle();
        String id = object.getString("id");

        try {
            URL profile_pic = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?width=200&height=150");
            Log.i("profile_pic", profile_pic + "");
            bundle.putString("profile_pic", profile_pic.toString());

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        bundle.putString("idFacebook", id);
        if (object.has("first_name"))
            bundle.putString("first_name", object.getString("first_name"));
        if (object.has("last_name"))
            bundle.putString("last_name", object.getString("last_name"));
        if (object.has("email"))
            bundle.putString("email", object.getString("email"));
        if (object.has("gender"))
            bundle.putString("gender", object.getString("gender"));
        if (object.has("birthday"))
            bundle.putString("birthday", object.getString("birthday"));
        if (object.has("location"))
            bundle.putString("location", object.getJSONObject("location").getString("name"));
        System.out.println("BUNDLEEE: "+bundle);
        return bundle;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bundle;
}
```

This works for me. You can use ProfileTracker also, but I find this more reliable.
Thanks